# Silex no error logging to server's error log

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am setting up a simple Silex project. With `$app['debug'] = false;` Silex does not log any errors to the server's error log (Nginx or FPM PHP).

Comment: What do you expect when you mention `$app['debug'] = false;` ? Do you feel it should log or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think silex WOULD log to the server's error log?

As stated [here](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html),

> Silex ships with a provider for Monolog which handles logging of errors. Check out the Providers chapter for details.

The [Monolog Service Provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/monolog.html) describes how to set up and use the logging provider:

> Services
>
> `monolog`: The monolog logger instance.
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
> $app['monolog']->addDebug('Testing the Monolog logging.');
> ```
>
> `monolog.listener`: An event listener to log requests, responses and errors.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the exceptions to server log instead of logging them manually?